# How to import or reproject SRTM 30 sec DEM

Tags: qgis, srtm

I downloaded the global SRTM DEM from [here](ftp://topex.ucsd.edu/pub/srtm30_plus/topo30/). When I add the DEM as a raster layer (in my case topo30.grs file) the left/western edge of the file is at Greenwich and the right/eastern edge is at +360 degrees. This makes the layer run off the right side of the required area. The western hemisphere needs to be negative up to -180 degrees. I have attached an image which shows what I mean. Is there an easy way to import it with the right projection or reproject the SRTM. I don't understand why they created the DEM like this in the first place. 
[image]

Comment: This might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134617/how-to-match-a-raster-netcdf-data-with-a-vector-layer-in-qgis

Comment: As noted above the answer is here: (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian)