# GDALwarp HDF5 Image With Unknown Projection

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, georeferencing, gdalwarp, hdf5

I have a NetCDF file that contains a series of HDF5 bands. I am looking to project one of these bands contained within this file. I've attempted to use the following command to achieve this:

```
gdalwarp -geoloc -of GTIFF -t_srs EPSG:4269 HDF5:"zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc"://Surface_temperature
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1: Unable to compute a GEOLOC_ARRAY based transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates for HDF5:zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc://Surface_temperature
```

My goal is to project this grid into the North American Datum reference (EPSG:4269), as metadata already indicates the coordinates are in lat lon. Any ideas as to why gdalwarp fails to project this?

The readout from the desired band to extract using `gdalinfo` is as follows:

```
    Size is 8192, 4096
    Coordinate System is `'
    Metadata:
      Conventions=CF-1.6
      created_date=2019-03-26 16:02:56
      institution=National Operational Hydrologic Remote Sensing Center, Chanhassen, MN
      references=http://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/technology/
      source=National Snow Analyses
      _nc3_strict=1
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
    Lower Left  (    0.0, 4096.0)
    Upper Right ( 8192.0,    0.0)
    Lower Right ( 8192.0, 4096.0)
    Center      ( 4096.0, 2048.0)
    Band 1 Block=8192x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
      Metadata:
        Surface_temperature_coordinates=lat lon
        Surface_temperature_grid_mapping=crs
        Surface_temperature_long_name=Surface temperature
        Surface_temperature_maximum_data_value=299.6
        Surface_temperature_minimum_data_value=238.9
        Surface_temperature_missing_value=-32768
        Surface_temperature_scale_factor=0.01
        Surface_temperature_standard_name=air_temperature
        Surface_temperature_start_date=2019-03-26 11:00:00
        Surface_temperature_stop_date=2019-03-26 11:00:00
        Surface_temperature_title=Scaled corrected Surface temperature analysis
        Surface_temperature_units=Kelvins
        Surface_temperature__FillValue=-32768
```

The gdalinfo result from the entire file is as follows:

```
Driver: HDF5/Hierarchical Data Format Release 5
Files: zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  Conventions=CF-1.6
  created_date=2019-03-26 16:02:56
  crs_grid_mapping_name=latitude_longitude
  crs_horizontal_datum=WGS84
  crs_inverse_flattening=298.257222096042
  crs_longitude_of_prime_meridian=0
  crs_semi_major_axis=6378137
  crs_semi_minor_axis=6356752.31414
  institution=National Operational Hydrologic Remote Sensing Center, Chanhassen, MN
  lat_axis=Y
  lat_bounds=lat_bounds
  lat_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
  lat_comment=location of pixel center
  lat_long_name=latitude
  lat_NAME=lat
  lat_origin_offset=0.00416666666667146
  lat_REFERENCE_LIST=
  lat_resolution=0.00833333333333333
  lat_standard_name=latitude
  lat_units=degrees_north
  lat__Netcdf4Dimid=0
  lon_axis=X
  lon_bounds=lon_bounds
  lon_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
  lon_comment=location of pixel center
  lon_long_name=longitude
  lon_NAME=lon
  lon_origin_offset=0.00416666666666052
  lon_REFERENCE_LIST=
  lon_resolution=0.00833333333333333
  lon_standard_name=longitude
  lon_units=degrees_east
  lon__Netcdf4Dimid=1
  nv_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
  nv_NAME=This is a netCDF dimension but not a netCDF variable.         2
  nv_REFERENCE_LIST=
  nv__Netcdf4Dimid=3
  references=http://www.nohrsc.noaa.gov/technology/
  source=National Snow Analyses
  Surface_temperature_coordinates=lat lon
  Surface_temperature_grid_mapping=crs
  Surface_temperature_long_name=Surface temperature
  Surface_temperature_maximum_data_value=299.6
  Surface_temperature_minimum_data_value=238.9
  Surface_temperature_missing_value=-32768
  Surface_temperature_scale_factor=0.01
  Surface_temperature_standard_name=air_temperature
  Surface_temperature_start_date=2019-03-26 11:00:00
  Surface_temperature_stop_date=2019-03-26 11:00:00
  Surface_temperature_title=Scaled corrected Surface temperature analysis
  Surface_temperature_units=Kelvins
  Surface_temperature__FillValue=-32768
  time_CLASS=DIMENSION_SCALE
  time_long_name=time
  time_NAME=time
  time_REFERENCE_LIST=
  time_units=hours since 2019-03-26 11:00:00
  time__Netcdf4Dimid=2
  _nc3_strict=1
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF5:"zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc"://Surface_temperature
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[1x4096x8192] //Surface_temperature (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF5:"zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc"://lat_bounds
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[4096x2] //lat_bounds (64-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF5:"zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc"://lon_bounds
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[8192x2] //lon_bounds (64-bit floating-point)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

Comment: Did you read this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134617/how-to-match-a-raster-netcdf-data-with-a-vector-layer-in-qgis

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319147/using-gdalwarp-for-reprojecting-netcdf-file and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154339/unable-to-warp-hdf5-files

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `gdalwarp -geoloc` still does not recognize lat and lon variables by itself (or at least I have not yet found out how to tell it ...).

But you can work around that using an intermediate VRT with `<Metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">` field.

1. Export the dataset as not georeferenced GTiff:

   ```bsh
   nodata_value=-32768
   scale_factor=0.01

   gdal_calc.py --format=GTiff --type=Float32 \
       -A "HDF5:zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc://Surface_temperature" \
       --calc="(A!=$nodata_value)*A*$scale_factor+(A==$nodata_value)*A" \
       --outfile tmpfile1.tif
   ```
2. Convert the result to VRT

   ```bsh
   gdal_translate -of VRT tmpfile1.tif tmpfile2.vrt
   ```
3. Add GEOLOCATION information to VRT:

   ```bsh
   <Metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">
     <MDI key="X_DATASET">HDF5:zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc://lon</MDI>
     <MDI key="X_BAND">1</MDI>
     <MDI key="Y_DATASET">HDF5:zz_ssmv01020S_latest.nc://lat</MDI>
     <MDI key="Y_BAND">1</MDI>
     <MDI key="PIXEL_OFFSET">0</MDI>
     <MDI key="LINE_OFFSET">0</MDI>
     <MDI key="PIXEL_STEP">1</MDI>
     <MDI key="LINE_STEP">1</MDI>
   </Metadata>
   ```

   (I do this automated using `sed -i '2i...' tmpfile2.vrt`)
4. Run `gdalwarp -geoloc` on the VRT

   ```bsh
   gdalwarp -of GTiff -geoloc -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4269 \
     -dstnodata "$nodata_value" \
     tmpfile2.vrt result.tif
   ```

Comment: Thanks for writing out a detailed process @RoVo . The code works well, however at step 4, I come to the following error: `ERROR 1: X_BAND and Y_BAND do not have the same dimensions`. Any insight as to what's throwing this error?